# How to get the actual chart width and height in chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I have line chart in canvas and want to know exact width and height of chart(not canvas width and height). 
Please help.

Answer (score 6):

The `chartArea` property contains an object that shows the area bounded by the x and y axes:

```
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  ...
});

console.log(myChart.chartArea);
```

Result:

```
{
  bottom: 500,
  left: 30,
  right: 1000,
  top: 30
}
```